# Constructing a method name

Tags: python, class, methods

How do I construct a method name to use with an instantiated class? I'm trying to run a method in a class 'jsonmaker' where the method corresponds to the datatype specified in the filein string.

```
for filein in filein_list:
    datatype = filein[(filein.find('_')):-8]
    method_name = pjoin(datatype + 'populate')
    instantiated_class.method_name(arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

When I try the above code I get the error message

```
'AttributeError: 'jsonmaker' object has no attribute 'method_name''
```

There is in fact a method in jsonmaker that matches pjoin(datatype + 'populate') so how do I tell the class to recognize that? Sorry if I'm not explaining this well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't reference the attribute of a class instance by putting a variable directly behind a dot reference. Not even when the variable references a string which is same as the name of the attribute.

You could instead use `getattr` to get the `method` from the string and then call it with those parameters:

```
getattr(instantiated_class, method_name)(arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I had though getattr was only for running a function on a variable who's name you don't know until the point of execution. Thanks.